# LVM RAID1 adding two more disks

Tags: lvm, software-raid, raid1

We have local server machine in our small company. Its running with Debian 8 on two 120GB SSDs merged in RAID1 with this tutorial.
https://blogging.dragon.org.uk/installing-ubuntu-14-04-on-raid-1-and-lvm/

Now we want to add 2 more 1TB disks, merge them in RAID1 as another RAID volume and redirect GIT repos and some mysql backup dumps there.

Our setup looks like this

```
md2 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
2960384 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
113215488 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
bitmap: 1/1 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
975296 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Ive read some tutorial
https://www.howtoforge.com/software-raid1-grub-boot-debian-etch

And now want to do this:

1. Create partitions on disks - sdc1 and sdd1
2. Set ***Linux raid autodetect*** type for them
3. Merge them in one volume

   mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md3 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
4. Update mdadm.conf configuration

   cp /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf_orig
   mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
5. Do the rest of work - set filesystem, add fstab line etc ...

Is this a good approach or is not as easy as im thinking? For example will there any troubles with GRUB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems fine, a few comments...

`--examine --scan` is just a starting point, you should edit the `mdadm.conf` to make sure there are no duplicate entries, add a mail address, remove unnecessary stuff (array lines only need the device name and uuid, nothing else)

```
MAILADDR your@admin.address
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=d8b8b4e5:e47b2e45:2093cd36:f654020d
ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=845b2454:42a319ef:6ec5238a:358c365b
ARRAY /dev/md2 UUID=23cf90d2:c05d720e:e72e178d:414a8128
```

`Linux raid autodetect` is deprecated (no harm in using the partition type anyway, but it's not required), RAID is assembled by `initramfs` and you might have to update that whenever you change your `mdadm.conf`, `fstab`.

Comment: I did everything like posted before and it works. Thank you for confirmation.